# Is Java EE paid for commerical usage?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to use Java in my web page but Java 11 is paid for commerical usage.Is it same for Java EE?

Comment: You don't need to pay in order to use any version of java for commercial purposes. You may need to pay in order to use the Oracle JVM, but you may use JVM from other vendors that do not require payment such as adopt openjdk: https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171129/334241 could be duplicate of the above post. @Cortex 4Z

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125833/is-java-free-software/125835#125835

Answer (score 5):

Java EE is not a product. It's just a collection of specifications.

There are various implementations from companies like Redhat, IBM, Oracle but also from open source projects like Apache TomEE, GlassFish, Wildfly some paid, some free and some with commerical support options.

In the last few month Java EE moved to the Eclipse Foundation and became the name Jakarta EE because of trademarks hold by Oracle. https://jakarta.ee/

Comment: Is all the EE in eclipse are jakarta?(Sry for bad english)

Comment: They are currently in the progress of transferring the specifications.

Comment: Is jakarta free for commerical usage?

Comment: Jakarta EE is like Java EE only the specification. No code! If you want a Java EE/Jakarta EE Server try Wildfly: https://wildfly.org/